# How to find the complex number has least and greatest modul satisfying a given condition?

Tags: complex

Let be given the complex number $z$ satisfying the condition $|z-2+2i|=2\sqrt{2}$. I want to find the complex numbers $z$ so that their modul obtain least and greatest value. I tried. Put $z = x + y i$.

From $|z-2+2i|=2\sqrt{2}$, we have 
$$|(x-2) + (y+2)i|=2\sqrt{2}.$$ 
Therefore, 
$$(x-2)^2 + (y+2)^2=8.$$ And then, I used

```
Maximize[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 8}, {x, y}]
```

> {32, {x -> 4, y -> -4}}

and

```
Minimize[{x^2 + y^2, (x - 2)^2 + (y + 2)^2 == 8}, {x, y}]
```

> {0, {x -> 0, y -> 0}}

I dont know why I can not use the command

```
Abs[(x - 2) + (y + 2) I]
```

to find the modul of `(x - 2) + (y + 2) I` and how to tell *Mathematica* to get the result $$(x-2)^2 + (y+2)^2=8$$ when I have 
$$|(x-2) + (y+2)i|=2\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed assumption that `x` and `y` are `Reals` which can be taken into accout by `ComplexExpand`:

```
ComplexExpand[Abs[(x - 2) + (y + 2) I]]^2
```

> ```
> (-2 + x)^2 + (2 + y)^2
> ```

So

```
Maximize[ComplexExpand /@ {Abs[x + I y], Abs[(x - 2) + (y + 2) I] == 2 Sqrt[2]}, {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {4 Sqrt[2], {x -> 4, y -> -4}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Solve[Abs[z - 2 + 2 I] == 2 Sqrt[2], {z}]
```

Comment: No. But I think, the solution does not exactly.